# Comparing Two different data type pairs?

Tags: java, arrays, object, stack

Im working on a problem to examine whether paranthesis are balanced or not in java.

Each paranthesis has a type and a type is a random integer number.

(0(1)1(2(0)0)2)0

^this would be considered balanced.

im using a stack to implement this however im confused as to how i would compare and/or pair the values to compair them?

This is what i have in place right now.

```
public class Parenthesis
{
private static final char OPEN = '(';
private static final char CLOSE = ')';

public static boolean isPair(char char1, char char2, int num1, int num2)
{
    if(char1 == OPEN && char2 == CLOSE && num1 == num2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean checkBalanced(int[] p, boolean[] b)
{
    Stack storage = new Stack(b.length);

    for(int i=0; i<p.length; i++)
    {
        if(b[i]==false)
        {
           char o=OPEN;
           int numO=p[i];
           storage.push(o, numO);
        }
        else if(b[i]==true)
        {
            char c=CLOSE;
            int numC=p[i];
            if (storage.isEmpty() || 
!isPair(storage.popSymb(),c,storage.popNum(),numC))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(storage.isEmpty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: I think that your example is wrong. Shouldn't be (0(1)1(2(3)3)2)0 ?

Comment: @OctavianR. sorry. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to realize this algorithm manually, you should realize few steps:

1. If symbol is open bracket, push it in stack.
2. If symbol is closed bracket:

   - If stack is not empty and last symbol in stack is open bracket, just pop open bracket.
   - Else push closed bracket in stack.
3. If stack will be empty as a result, your expression is balanced.

E.g.

```
public class Parenthesis {
private static final char OPEN = '(';
private static final char CLOSE = ')';

private static boolean checkBalanced(String str) {

    Stack<Character> storage = new Stack<>();

    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    for (char ch : chars) {
        if (ch == OPEN) {
            storage.push(ch);
        }

        if (ch == CLOSE) {
            if (storage.size() != 0 && storage.peek() == OPEN) {
                storage.pop();
            } else {
                storage.push(ch);
            }
        }
    }

    return storage.size() == 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(checkBalanced("(0(1)1(2(3)2)2)0"));
}
```

But I advise you to use the reverse Polish notation to implement this algorithm.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation
http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm

Comment: Thanks for the input! I can understand how youre implementing this however im bound to use the method with the following parameters:  
checkBalanced(int[] p, boolean[] b) where boolean b[] is an array of true, false. false being open parenthesis and true being closed. and also ive implemented my own stack for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can help you in a way:

import java.util.Stack;

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Parenthesis {

    private static class Pair {

        private final char parenthesis;
        private final char number;

        Pair(String value) {
            this.parenthesis = value.charAt(0);
            this.number = value.charAt(1);
        }

        boolean canFormAPairWith(Pair pair) {
            if (parenthesis == ')') {
                return false;
            }
            return this.number == pair.number && pair.parenthesis == ')';
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack<Pair> stack = new Stack<>();

        String example = "(0(1)1(2(0)0)2)0";
        for (String s : example.split("(?<=\\G.{2})")) {

            Pair currentPair = new Pair(s);
            if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek().canFormAPairWith(currentPair)) {
                stack.pop();
            } else {
                stack.push(currentPair);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(stack.isEmpty());

    }
}
```

I didn't tested for all cases, but for your case works.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

There is tool for that!

**No need to write any Java code.** Just use [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) with the grammar given below.

Yes, your input `(0(1)1(2(0)0)2)0` passes as balanced.

## ANTLR 4

[ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) is a language-recognition tool.

- **Phase 1**
  You feed ANTLR a “grammar” file defining a programming language (Java, C, COBOL, whatever)  or a data structure (XML, JSON, CSV, whatever), and ANTLR generates Java source code for a lexer & parser.
- **Phase 2**
  You compile those sources. Then run those classes, feeding your source code or data file to be analyzed.

  - **Lexing**
    The character stream is processed to identify the words formerly known as *tokens*.
  - **Parsing**
    The stream of tokens are processed to identify the sentences (the statements in a programming language, or the rows in a data file). The result of this is an [*Abstract Syntax Tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

Use the `TestRig` class bundled with ANTLR 4 to input your value by console or by file. If your input string of numbers and parens are not properly balanced, the lexing-parsing will signal an error.

I am but a newbie with ANTLR, but this grammar I adapted from [an example](https://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/code/tour/Expr.g4) in [*The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15812592-the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) by [Terence Parr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_Parr) (creator of [the ANTLR project](https://www.antlr.org)), seems to be doing the job for you.

```
grammar ParenBalance;

prog:   stat+ ;

stat:   expr NEWLINE
    |   NEWLINE
    ;

expr:  expr expr
    |   INT
    |   '(' expr ')'
    ;

INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS  :   [ \t]+  ;
```

Try some inputs (all with a [Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), not shown):

- `42` passes
- `(42)` passes
- `(42` fails, missing ')'
- `42)` fails, extraneous input ')'
- `(((1)2)3)` passes
- `((1 2)3)` fails, mismatched input ' ', extraneous input ')'

Let's try your input.

- `(0(1)1(2(0)0)2)0` passes.

Here is a screenshot of ANTLR 4 in action via the [ANTLR4 plugin](https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/) for [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) IDE. Click to zoom. **ANTLR is actually driven either by the console or by Java code.** The plugin shown here handles that interaction on our behalf so we can work conveniently within the IDE.

[image: screenshot of ANTLR 4 in action within IntelliJ IDE via the ANTLR4 plugin]